# Knife bootstrapping returns "Log level must be one of :debug, :info, :warn, :error, or :fatal"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, knife

When boot-strapping a VM

```
$ knife bootstrap localhost --ssh-user vagrant --ssh-password vagrant --ssh-port 2222 --sudo
```

The bootstrap process returns the following exception:

```
Bootstrapping Chef on localhost
localhost /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-log-1.4.1/lib/mixlib/log.rb:97:in `level=': Log level must be one of :debug, :info, :warn, :error, or :fatal (ArgumentError)
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application.rb:117:in `configure_logging'
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:242:in `configure_logging'
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application.rb:63:in `reconfigure'
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:197:in `reconfigure'
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application.rb:68:in `run'
localhost   from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
localhost   from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
localhost   from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

I just updated my chef version:

```
$ knife -v
Chef 11.8.0
```

Is this a bug from chef?

Comment: could you post your `knife.rb`

Comment: Hi Ryan, were you able to find a solution? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact problem where the version of Chef I was telling bootstrap to install was 10.30.2.

However, the version of Chef running on my local machine was 11.

Once I had Chef version 10 on my local machine, the error about the log level disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

the error trace indicates that it's thrown from `chef-client`. so you need to check `/etc/chef/client.rb`.

You need an entry there like:

```
log_level   :info
```

Refer to article [About client.rb](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/client_rb.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for this, what i consider to be a bug in not being able to  bootstrap chef 10.x client using chef/knife version 11.

You can put this in your knife.rb

```
chef_client_path 'chef-client -l info'
```

Chris Jerdonek posted a workaround here [Knife bootstraping returns Log level must be one of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944901/knife-bootstraping-returns-log-level-must-be-one-of)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occurred when I tried to knife bootstrap without being in the same directory as knife.rb